# Cubecamera Refraction envMap pixelated

Tags: three.js, webgl, pixelate

I'm using a cubeCamera to get refraction material on my mesh (here a cube).

`var myCubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 70, 512 )
myCubeCamera.renderTarget.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;`

When a use the `CubeReflectionMapping` the reflection looks quite good but with `CubeRefractionMapping` I get a weird pixelated texture like on the picture. I manage to resolve this problem by increase the `cubeResolution` to 2048 but performance are so bad :/.

[image]

[Here the fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpbdwup/)

So I'm looking for another way to solve the problem without degraded the frame rate.

Comment: Hmmm... `CubeCamera.renderTarget` does not have a `mapping` property.... In spite of that, what you are doing does work. Can you provide a _simple_ live link to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I expect you can figure out how to create an example unrelated to your client's work.

Comment: I updated my post to add the fiddlejs : http://jsfiddle.net/vrpbdwup/